# Access Denied when trying to Start Windows Services

Tags: windows

I have a Windows 7 machine that I am trying to start Function Discovery Resource Publication service and a few others for network and file discovery. However when I try to start the service I get Access Denied. I am an Admin so I should have access to start services. I am at a lost right now. I tried to start the services in Safe Mode and still no luck. I even created a new admin user and still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you trying to start the service?  If using the Services administrative tool, did you remember to right-click and select "Run as administrator"?

Comment: I thought that was the case and that was one of the first things that I did, no luck. I am using the services panel from admin tools.